# Why does $x^{m \cdot 2^i} \equiv -1$ with odd $m$ imply that $x$ has order $m \cdot 2^{i+1}$?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

It is clear that $$x^{m \cdot 2^{i+1}} \equiv 1$$ for odd $m$ but is there a theorem or an obvious reason why $x$ cannot have order smaller than $m \cdot 2^{i+1}$?

Context: I am trying to understand the proof about the accuracy of the Miller-Rabin-Test that is given [here](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~schoof/millerrabinpom.pdf) on page two. There are additional conditions that apply, but the author doesn't mention any of them when calling the implication, so I assume that this is generally true and there is a fairly obvious argument for it that I overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of $x$ need not be equal to $m2^{i+1}$. It could be $q2^{i+1}$ where $q$ is a proper divisor of $m$.

Examples are easy to make. For instance, work modulo $5$. Then $2$ has order $1\cdot 2^2$, and $2^{35\cdot 2}\equiv -1\pmod{5}$.

**Remark:** We **can** say that $2^{i+1}$ is the largest power of $2$ that divides the order of $x$. For suppose to the contrary that $x$ has order $w2^e$, where $w$ is odd. Since $(x^{m2^i})^2\equiv 1$, it follows that $w2^e$ divides $m2^{i+1}$, so $e\le i+1$. And we cannot have $e=i$, for $(x^{w2^i})^m\equiv -1$.

Comment: That actually is sufficient for the proof that I linked. The author only claims that $2^{i+1}$ is the largest power of 2 dividing the order. Guess I got a little confused when trying to understand what he meant. Thanks!

Comment: That much **is** true.